# Split one level of an multi index into columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["foo","fizz",1],["foo","fizz",2],["foo","buzz",3],["foo","buzz",4],["bar","fizz",6],["bar","buzz",8]],columns=["a","b","c"])

       a    b     c
    0  foo  fizz  1
    1  foo  fizz  2
    2  foo  buzz  3
    3  foo  buzz  4
    4  bar  fizz  6
    5  bar  buzz  8
```

That I can group:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["a","b"]).sum()

              c
    a   b
    bar buzz  8
        fizz  6
    foo buzz  7
        fizz  3
```

Which is awesome! But what I really need, instead of the "c" column is two columns, "foo" and "bar":

```
          foo  bar
    b
    buzz  7    8
    fizz  3    6
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this? I tried searching, but I guess I don't have the correct terminology for this so I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try `df2.unstack(level='a')`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for that:

```
df2.unstack(level='a')
```

Example:

```
In [146]: df2.unstack(level='a')
Out[146]:
       c
a    bar foo
b
buzz   8   7
fizz   6   3
```

After that you'll get multiindexed columns. If you need to get flat dataframe you could use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) of multiindex:

```
df3 = df2.unstack(level='a')
df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel()

In [177]: df3
Out[177]:
a     bar  foo
b
buzz    8    7
fizz    6    3
```

**EDIT**

`droplevel` drops level from MultiIndex which your columns become after `unstack`. By default it drops level 0 which is what you need for that dataframe.

Copy from `help(pd.core.index.MultiIndex.droplevel)`:

> Help on function **droplevel** in module pandas.core.index:
>
> **droplevel**(self, level=0)
> Return Index with requested level removed. If MultiIndex has only 2
> levels, the result will be of Index type not MultiIndex.
>
> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> level : int/level name or list thereof
>
> Notes
> -----
> Does not check if result index is unique or not
>
> Returns
> -------
> index : Index or MultiIndex
> ```

Comment: Exactly what I need :) can you explain a bit what the droplevel() does?