# Split second level multindex column to create three level column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Given a multiindex `df`

```
       X                     
  E1_ex0 E1_ex2 E2_ex0 E4_ex0
0      3      4      1      1
1      4      3      2      0
```

I would like to split the second level at `_` and push the second item as the third level as below

```
       X            
       E1      E2  E4
      ex0 ex2 ex0 ex0
    0      3      4      1      1
    1      4      3      2      0
```

May I know how to do this?

The original `df` can be created as per the code below

```
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 4))
tuples = [('X', 'E1_ex0'), ('X', 'E1_ex2'), ('X', 'E2_ex0'), ('X', 'E4_ex0')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples))
```

I try to find on the net, but unable to find relevant resource.

I think the closest example is as in this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247373/6446053), but I am struggling to split only the second level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the multiindex columns and construct a third level indexing by unpacking the split list.

```py
tuples = [(index[0], *index[1].split('_')) for index in df.columns]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df.values, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples))

# or without creating new DataFrame

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(index[0], *index[1].split('_')) for index in df.columns])
```

```
print(df2)

    X
   E1      E2  E4
  ex0 ex2 ex0 ex0
0   1   0   3   3
1   0   1   4   3
```